# Is it possible to use "Coded UI" on a form launched in memory rather than a compiled executable?

Tags: .net, winforms, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to run the coded UI framework against a form loaded in memory (on another thread)* rather than a compiled executable and it seems to work OK for some controls but not others. Specifically, a "UITestControlNotFoundException" is thrown when attempting to locate the (invisible) windows that are the direct parents of the actual controls (buttons, labels etc.).

An example that shows the issue:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting

<CodedUITest()>
Public Class CodedUITest2

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub CodedUITestMethod1()
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 500
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.MaximumRetryCount = 1

        Dim Thread As New Threading.Thread _
            (Sub()
                 Dim Form = New Form()
                 Form.Text = "Foo"
                 Form.Controls.Add(New Button)
                 Form.Controls(0).Name = "Bar"
                 Form.Visible = True
                 Application.Run(Form)
             End Sub)
        Thread.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
        Thread.Start()

        'Find UI test control
        Dim UIWindow = New WinControls.WinWindow
        UIWindow.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "Foo")
        UIWindow.WaitForControlExist(5000) '<--This works

        Dim UIButton As New WinControls.WinButton(UIWindow)
        UIButton.Find() '<--This works

        Dim UIButtonWindow As New WinControls.WinWindow(UIWindow)
        UIButtonWindow.SearchProperties.Add(WinControls.WinControl.PropertyNames.ControlName, "Bar")
        UIButtonWindow.Find() '<--This does NOT work
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I run the same test using a compiled exe (with the button already added) then `UIButtonWindow` element is found OK.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to get this working? Or whether this is just a stupid thing to be doing?

*If you are wondering about the reasoning behind wanting to do this, its because I'm attempting to write some unit tests for wrappers I've created that encapsulate the functionally-bare Microsoft UI test controls. The tests would be more atomic if I could have them create their own forms/controls as needed rather than rely on some separately compiled exe.

PS. I'm running this in VS2015 using .NET 4.5.2 on a Windows 10 box.

Comment: If you want to find the button like the form by its `Text`, you need to set text of button: `Form.Controls(0).Text = "Bar"`. Then use this search expression: `UIButtonWindow.SearchProperties.Add(WinControls.WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, "Bar")`

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't help. As I mentioned in the question: the scenario works when running against a compiled exe but not when invoking the form at runtime.

Comment: No problem, it was an answer to **Has anyone got any ideas on how to get this working**. I tried this and it works for both executable and your case. But it doesn't describe why your code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Coded UI, but the test code shown has two obvious (for people having WF experience) threading issues. First, the form creation (starting with `Dim Form`) should happen on the UI thread, so that block should be moved inside the `Thread` procedure (before `Form.Visible = True` line). Second, the UI thread should be made STA by adding `Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)` before `Thread.Start()`

Comment: @IvanStoev I've updated the example with your suggestions but the result is the same.

Comment: @SimonB I wasn't sure if that's causing the OP issue, that's why I wrote  comment rather than answer. At least we eliminated one possible cause and made the code WF compatible, now maybe someone will find the actual issue. Good luck!